# POS UI components plugin

Tags: javascript, user-interface, pos

Not sure if this is the place for this kind of questions but hope you can help me. I'm developing a Point Of Sale (POS) for a small supermarket. Modules like Product registration and Stocks are almost finished but POS interface needs to be improved. Consider this layout:
[image: pos_layout]
I want to know if there's some UI plugins for the numbers panel and products panel. I know there's numpad plugins but all of them (at least, all I've seen) are linked to a input field.

This app is intented to be used on mobile devices too.

Thanks in advance.